# why searching requires separate search server

Tags: database, solr, lucene

I worked on the Apache Server for a period of time. However, I could not explain to somebody who ask me why do we need to have separate server for searching while we can retrieve the results from database as well using LIKE operator.

I know results can be retrieved faster using Solr Server but I want to know does we get better results from Solr as compared to results from Database ?

Also I could not understanding the meaning of "full-text search" as one of feature of Apache Solr Server.

Comment: it doesn't. but a standalone search server is usually faster and more feature-filled

Answer (score 1):

Solr has inbuilt many features..
Like search, faceting, more like, suggest etc.

You may achieve some features with the help of database but you may need to a lot of effort for the same.

And the benefit of using solr is...application won't be adding any extra load on the current database... And it gives other features with as mentioned earlier...

Full text search is also provided by database like oracle but it's a paid function.

Here full text search means you can extract the data or content of file and search the data of it.

Solr uses lucene ...you can use lucene directly for your application but using solr makes you to use lot of available features and you save a lot of time in re building the same.